# Compilation error with the Java ternary

Tags: java

For a string `foo`, and a regular expression `REGEX`, why doesn't this work:

`foo.indexOf(foo.matches(REGEX) ? '<' : "--");`

what is wrong with this ternary?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does the compiler not like it? Did it make you a plate of oysters not to your liking?

Comment: What do you expect the type of the expression to be? Your second argument is of type `char`, and the third argument is of type `String`. There's no conversion between those types.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think the inferred type of the expression `foo.matches(REGEX) ? '<' : "--"` is something like `Serializable` (?). The problem is that `String` does not have an `indexOf` method that accepts a `Serializable`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington: Indeed. I'm surprised that expression compiles at all... shows I'm more used to the C# rules than the Java ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two expressions of the ternary conditional have to be the same type (or implicitly convertible to a common type). `'<'` and `"--"` are respectively a `char` and a `java.lang.String`. One cannot be implicitly converted into the other.

To fix, use the more long-winded

```
foo.matches(REGEX) ? foo.indexOf('<') : foo.indexOf("--");
```

Two different overloads of `indexOf` are used here but since the return types are identical the ternary conditional is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this `'<'` to `"<"`

Comment: Beautiful in its simplicity. Plus one.